# Video player on iPad that doesn't stretch to full screen

Tags: ipad, applications

I'm looking for a video player that doesn't stretch my 640x480 video files to full screen (1024x768), which degrades the quality IMHO.

Is such an app available?

Answer (score 1):

[OPLayerHD](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/oplayer-hd-best-video-music/id373236724?mt=8) allows you to select the stretching mode, so you can select between full screen and actual ration of the video.

There is also a lite version, maybe you can try that one before buying the complete OPlayerHD

Alternativelly there was AVPlayerHD, which seems to be not available now.

Comment: I just tried it, but this app also does stretch, although remains the right aspect ratio.

Comment: @MikeB Have you tried to double-tap on the video?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't do anything. Tried also pinching without result. I did found the aspect ratio option, but that does only influence the ratio, not stretching. Btw: I did use the lite version.

Comment: @MikeB I'm using the complete version, which changes the ration with double-tap. If you have a way to install AVPlayerHD that will work for sure.

Answer (score -3):

How about [nPlayer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nplayer/id539397400?mt=8)? It allows you to adjust the size of the video you're watching.

> nPlayer provides high quality video play performance and easy control-UI supporting almost all kinds of video formats and codecs without file converting efforts.